# add custom design to Views Row

Tags: 7, views

i need to add custom css id/class to views row after row first. example:

in default i see this :

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first"></div>

<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even"></div>

<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last"></div>
```

Now, I need change this to:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first"></div>

<div id="leftCol" class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even"></div>

<div id="leftCol" class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last"></div>
```

Actually i need to print result like this:

```
 <div>views-row-first</div> <-- example: 100% width

 <div>views-row-even</div> <-- example: 50% width + <div> views-row-last</div> <-- example: 50% width
```

With this i combination of one and two columns. 100% width and one column for first row And at the bottom 2*50% and two column for other(even/odd/last). How to?

**NOTE:** i work with content-node / unforrmatted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just add the 100% to `views-row-1` and width: 50% to `views-row`?
I believe that you do it like this:

```
.views-row {
  width: 50%;
  //other css
}

.views-row-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you can create a template file for rows output and wrap the each row of your view with your class, `go -> view settings -> advanced -> theme information`. you will see it theme